# OpenFileDialog Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Не пойму, где, что делаю не так с `OpenFileDialog` в Silverlight? Знаю,что его использование немного отличается, чем  в Window Forms, но я вроде это учитываю и все равно ошибка в пути к файлу в строке:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.File.OpenRead());
```

Вот в контексте:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
        string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";

            var matches = 
                lines.SelectMany(line=> Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
                    .Cast<Match>()).Where(m => m.Success)
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                    .Distinct();

            foreach (String match in matches)
            {

                    textBox1.AppendText(match + Environment.NewLine);
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать вот так:

```
OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.File.FullName);
                    string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";

                    var matches =
                        lines.SelectMany(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
                            .Cast<Match>()).Where(m => m.Success)
                            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                            .Distinct();

                    foreach (String match in matches)
                    {
                        textBox1.AppendText(match + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
```

Так как OpenFileDialog возвращает тип bool?.
Информация о выбранном файле (opendialog.File) имеет тип [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.96%29.aspx)

Comment: AvtPhenix, спасибо! На самом деле, так пробовал делать тоже.И Считаю такой способ логичным, но было отказано в пути. Нашел здесь http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-OpenFileDialog-in-Silverlight.aspx.